# Encountered error in connecting the C++ and pypy with cppyy

Tags: c++, pypy

I wrote a class header file like this, all steps follows this page [cppyy](https://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/improve-docs/cppyy.html)

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int i = -99) : m_myint(i) {}

    int GetMyInt() { return m_myint; }
    void SetMyInt(int i) { m_myint = i; }

public:
    int m_myint;
};
```

And then compile it

```
$ genreflex MyClass.h
$ g++ -fPIC -rdynamic -O2 -shared -I$REFLEXHOME/include MyClass_rflx.cpp -o libMyClassDict.so -L$REFLEXHOME/lib -lReflex
```

Load to pypy-c

```
$ pypy-c
>>>> import cppyy
>>>> cppyy.load_reflection_info("libMyClassDict.so")
```

Then I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: libMyClassDict.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Anyone has encountered this problem, help me please!

Comment: Does the file exist? Was the call to `g++` successful?

Comment: g++ run successfully, and the libMyClassDict.so exists too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(solved after discussion in the pypy mailing list)

The issue was that `"libMyClassDict.so"` is looked up in the system's standard paths (not including `"."`).  You need to say `"./libMyClassDict.so"`.